# SQL How many times B appears in A

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem on which I have spent over 3 hours now. It goes like this.
Below is the table with Columns animal_id and birds_id:

```
animal_id | bird_id
      1    |    1
      3    |    3
      5    |    2
      2    |    1
      6    |    1
```

I need to write an SQL query that counts Birds, in how many Animals the Bird appear in.
Output should be:

```
Number of Animals | Number of Birds
         3        |      1
         1        |      2
```

Explanation: Above output shows that 
Row 1 : one element in Birds (Bird_id:1) appeared in Animals for 3 times. 
Row 2 : two elements in Birds (Bird_id:2 and Bird_id:3) each appeared once in Animals.

My work so far: With all the efforts I could do only so much :(

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT bird_id) AS D FROM myTable GROUP BY bird_id;
```

Output so far:

```
 3   |   1
 1   |   1
 1   |   1
```

I am not very good in SQL queries. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL anr/or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `Number of Animals`, 
       COUNT(*) AS `Number of Birds`
FROM (
  SELECT bird_id, COUNT(*) AS `Number of Animals`
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY bird_id ) AS t
GROUP BY `Number of Animals`
```

You need one more level of aggregation to get at the desired result.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4eea0/6)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to apply count on bird_id, Try this :

```
select mt.number_of_Animal,count(*) from (select count(*) Number_of_animal, bird_id Bird_id from mytable group by bird_id) mt group by mt.number_of_Animal ;
```